# R - save as data.frame all elements of a list of lists efficiently

Tags: r, list

I have the following list, and I want to create a data.frame that holds every possible "path", when the numeric value of the arrays is> 0.

This is the list:

```
> ABBCCD2
$A1
$A1$B1
      D1    D2
C1 0.233 0.078
C2 0.039 0.039

$A1$B2
      D1    D2
C1 0.083 0.028
C2 0.056 0.056

$A1$B3
      D1    D2
C1 0.083 0.028
C2 0.056 0.056


$A2
$A2$B1
      D1    D2
C1 0.100 0.033
C2 0.017 0.017

$A2$B2
   D1 D2
C1  0  0
C2  0  0

$A2$B3
   D1 D2
C1  0  0
C2  0  0
```

And this is the result I want:

```
> res
   FUN INTC INTB INME  prob
1   A1   B1   C1   D1 0.233
2   A1   B1   C1   D2 0.078
3   A1   B1   C2   D1 0.039
4   A1   B1   C2   D2 0.039
5   A1   B2   C1   D1 0.083
6   A1   B2   C1   D2 0.028
7   A1   B2   C2   D1 0.056
8   A1   B2   C2   D2 0.056
9   A1   B3   C1   D1 0.083
10  A1   B3   C1   D2 0.028
11  A1   B3   C2   D1 0.056
12  A1   B3   C2   D2 0.056
13  A2   B1   C1   D1 0.100
14  A2   B1   C1   D2 0.033
15  A2   B1   C2   D1 0.017
16  A2   B1   C2   D2 0.017
```

I have solved it with for loops, but it is not efficient, since the real problem that I have there are 15 million possible paths, and it can take several days to solve it.
This is the code I have made:

```
m <- 0

# creamos dataframe vacio
res <- data.frame(FUN=character(),INTC=character(),INTB=character(),INME=character(),prob=numeric())


for(i in 1:length(ABBCCD2)) { # A
  
 
  for (j in 1:length(ABBCCD2[[1]])) {  # B
    
    
    for(k in 1:nrow(ABBCCD2[[1]][[1]])) {  # C
      
      
      for(f in 1:ncol(ABBCCD2[[1]][[1]])) {  # D
       
        
        # solo guardamos las prob > 0
        if(ABBCCD2[[i]][[j]][k,f] > 0) {
        
        
            # contador de caminos con probabilidad no-cero
            m <- m + 1
            
            
            # creamos la fila del data frame correspondiente y vamos rellenando
            res[m,] <- data.frame(FUN=names(ABBCCD2[i]), INTC=names(ABBCCD2[[i]][j]), INTB=rownames(ABBCCD2[[i]][[j]])[k], 
                                 
                                 INME = colnames(ABBCCD2[[i]][[j]])[f] , prob = ABBCCD2[[i]][[j]][k,f] )
        }else{
          
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas to solve it more efficiently?

Thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option

```
library(rrapply)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
map_depth(ABBCCD2, 2, ~ as.data.frame.table(.x)) %>% 
  map_dfr(~ bind_rows(.x, .id = 'INTC'), .id = 'FUN') %>% 
  rename_at(3:5, ~c("INTB", "INME", "prob"))  %>% 
  filter(prob != 0)
```

-output

```
#    FUN INTC INTB INME       prob
#1   A1   B1   C1   D1 -1.0978872
#2   A1   B1   C2   D1 -0.8782714
#3   A1   B1   C1   D2  0.1646925
#4   A1   B1   C2   D2  1.2239280
#5   A1   B2   C1   D1  0.2088934
#6   A1   B2   C2   D1  0.2191693
#7   A1   B2   C1   D2 -1.6247005
#8   A1   B2   C2   D2 -0.4496129
#9   A2   B1   C1   D1  0.3426282
#10  A2   B1   C2   D1 -1.0963979
#11  A2   B1   C1   D2  1.8424623
#12  A2   B1   C2   D2 -0.2248845
#13  A2   B2   C1   D1 -0.9655256
#14  A2   B2   C2   D1  0.6998366
#15  A2   B2   C1   D2 -1.2647063
#16  A2   B2   C2   D2  0.4514344
```

#### data

```
ABBCCD2 <- list(A1 = list(B1 = structure(c(-1.0978871935389, -0.878271447742256, 
0.164692499183084, 1.22392804082201), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("C1", "C2"), c("D1", "D2"))), B2 = structure(c(0.208893448902667, 
0.21916929248291, -1.62470051990683, -0.449612869059051), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("C1", "C2"), c("D1", "D2")))), A2 = list(
    B1 = structure(c(0.34262819072166, -1.09639792471103, 1.8424623311698, 
    -0.224884516346163), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("C1", 
    "C2"), c("D1", "D2"))), B2 = structure(c(-0.965525564286861, 
    0.699836580462635, -1.26470634026811, 0.451434438203962), .Dim = c(2L, 
    2L), .Dimnames = list(c("C1", "C2"), c("D1", "D2"))), B3 = structure(c(0, 
    0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("C1", "C2"
    ), c("D1", "D2")))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much akrun,
Your solution is very efficient :)
I think I should start studying tydiverse programming.

Comment: What a fancy solution! Liked it!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, the challenges are

- to convert the matrices to data.frames,
- to skip zero matrices,
- to bind all pieces from the nested lists into one large dataset,
- to reshape into long format,
- to retain the names of list elements and matrix dimensions.

(Execution not necessarily in that order)

An additional challenge was that the question shows the nested list in *printed* form but not in a *reproducible* form, e.g., `dput()`. See the *Data* section on turning the printout into a list structure.

---

For the sake of completeness, here are two other approaches.

- nested `lapply()` and `rbindlist()`
- `rrapply::rrapply()` and `reshape2::melt()`

### Nested `lapply()` and `rbindlist()`

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
res <- lapply(
  ABBCCD2, 
  function(x) lapply(x, as.data.table, keep.rownames = "INTB") %>% rbindlist(idcol = "INTC")
) %>% 
  rbindlist(idcol = "FUN") %>% 
  melt(measure.vars = patterns("^D"), variable.name = "INME", value.name = "prob") %>% 
  .[prob != 0] %>%
  setorderv(names(.))
res
```

> ```
>     FUN INTC INTB INME  prob
>  1:  A1   B1   C1   D1 0.233
>  2:  A1   B1   C1   D2 0.078
>  3:  A1   B1   C2   D1 0.039
>  4:  A1   B1   C2   D2 0.039
>  5:  A1   B2   C1   D1 0.083
>  6:  A1   B2   C1   D2 0.028
>  7:  A1   B2   C2   D1 0.056
>  8:  A1   B2   C2   D2 0.056
>  9:  A1   B3   C1   D1 0.083
> 10:  A1   B3   C1   D2 0.028
> 11:  A1   B3   C2   D1 0.056
> 12:  A1   B3   C2   D2 0.056
> 13:  A2   B1   C1   D1 0.100
> 14:  A2   B1   C1   D2 0.033
> 15:  A2   B1   C2   D1 0.017
> 16:  A2   B1   C2   D2 0.017
> ```

`magrittr` piping is used to improve readability.

This approach converts the single 2 x 2 matrices into data.tables with 3 columns and 2 rows each. These are then combined by `rbindlist()` in two steps to form one large data.table. Finally, the two value columns are reshaped to long format and zero `prob` values are removed.

`setorderv()` is only used to allow for a direct comparison with OP's expected result.

**Caveat:** Zero `prob` values are removed after all data have been turned into long format. This may lead to unexpected results in case one of the matrices contains a zero element just by chance.

### rrapply() and matrix `melt()`

Here is a different approach which first reshapes the matrices to long form data.tables (after excluding matrices with *all* zero elements) which are then combined into one large dataset by two `rbindlist()` steps:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(rrapply)
res2 <- rrapply(ABBCCD2, 
                condition = function(x) sum(abs(x)) > 0, 
                f = function(x) reshape2::melt(x, value.name = "prob"), 
                classes = "matrix", how = "prune") %>% 
  lapply(rbindlist, idcol = "INTC") %>% 
  rbindlist(idcol = "FUN") %>% 
  setnames(c("Var1", "Var2"), c("INTB", "INME"))%>%
  setorderv(names(.))
res2
```

The result is the same as above.

### Data

Here is a way to turn the printout into a nested list structure:

```
txt <- "$A1
$A1$B1
D1    D2
C1 0.233 0.078
C2 0.039 0.039

$A1$B2
D1    D2
C1 0.083 0.028
C2 0.056 0.056

$A1$B3
D1    D2
C1 0.083 0.028
C2 0.056 0.056


$A2
$A2$B1
D1    D2
C1 0.100 0.033
C2 0.017 0.017

$A2$B2
D1 D2
C1  0  0
C2  0  0

$A2$B3
D1 D2
C1  0  0
C2  0  0"
```

`txt` contains the printout as copied and pasted from the question

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(rrapply)

ABBCCD2 <- fread(text = txt, sep = NULL, header = FALSE, blank.lines.skip = TRUE) %>% 
  .[, tstrsplit(V1, "\\$")] %>% 
  .[, c("V2", "V3") := zoo::na.locf(.SD, na.rm = FALSE), .SDcols = c("V2", "V3")] %>% 
  .[V1 != ""] %>% 
  split(by = c("V2", "V3"), flatten = FALSE, keep.by = FALSE) %>% 
  rrapply(
    f = . %>% 
      .[, paste0(V1, collapse = "\n") %>% 
          {paste("rn", .)} %>% 
          fread() %>% 
          as.matrix(rownames = "rn")]
    , classes = "data.frame", how = "replace")


ABBCCD2
```

> ```
> $A1
> $A1$B1
>       D1    D2
> C1 0.233 0.078
> C2 0.039 0.039
>
> $A1$B2
>       D1    D2
> C1 0.083 0.028
> C2 0.056 0.056
>
> $A1$B3
>       D1    D2
> C1 0.083 0.028
> C2 0.056 0.056
>
>
> $A2
> $A2$B1
>       D1    D2
> C1 0.100 0.033
> C2 0.017 0.017
>
> $A2$B2
>    D1 D2
> C1  0  0
> C2  0  0
>
> $A2$B3
>    D1 D2
> C1  0  0
> C2  0  0
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `stack`

```
rev(
  transform(
    stack(df <- as.data.frame(
      rapply(ABBCCD2,
        t,
        how = "replace"
      )
    )),
    ind = paste0(ind, ".", row.names(df))
  )
)
```

which gives

```
           ind     values
1  A1.B1.C1.D1 -1.0978872
2  A1.B1.C1.D2  0.1646925
3  A1.B1.C2.D1 -0.8782714
4  A1.B1.C2.D2  1.2239280
5  A1.B2.C1.D1  0.2088934
6  A1.B2.C1.D2 -1.6247005
7  A1.B2.C2.D1  0.2191693
8  A1.B2.C2.D2 -0.4496129
9  A2.B1.C1.D1  0.3426282
10 A2.B1.C1.D2  1.8424623
11 A2.B1.C2.D1 -1.0963979
12 A2.B1.C2.D2 -0.2248845
13 A2.B2.C1.D1 -0.9655256
14 A2.B2.C1.D2 -1.2647063
15 A2.B2.C2.D1  0.6998366
16 A2.B2.C2.D2  0.4514344
17 A2.B3.C1.D1  0.0000000
18 A2.B3.C1.D2  0.0000000
19 A2.B3.C2.D1  0.0000000
20 A2.B3.C2.D2  0.0000000
```